# How to use the facebook send dialog but send a message and not a link

Tags: facebook, messenger

Everythin is in the title :

I want people that are on my website to send facebook messages between each others (between respective friends) : they signup on my site with their facebook account, and I know their friends. I just want them to easily talk between them without having to switch to facebook.

Or at least, if that is not possible, I want to open a new tab with their facebook on messenger with a prefilled `to:` field.

I never imagined this information could be so difficult to find

Comment: prefilling is not allowed, and not possible anyway. you can only create your own messaging system, but you cannot use facebook messenger for this, there is no api for it.

Comment: Do you have any source about this ?  I have several (famous) applications that does prepopulate the send dialogue when sharing on messenger. Uber Eat's referral for instance, or Airbnb's. Do they have a partnership with Messenger ?